# How to get the output file format(with defined spaces) as same as input file format when passing through loops

Tags: awk, sed, for

I need to get the output file same as the input file format after passing through the while loop.

eg:

```
cat samp.csv

a     b           c              d
```

```
cat samp.csv | while IFS= read -r line
do
echo $line
done
```

after passing samp.csv in while
output :

```
 
a b c d
```

expected output :

```
a     b           c              d
```

Could anyone please suggest me?

Comment: See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: You got the answer and some further reading a few days ago in comments and a referenced duplicate question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/71357970/1745001 so why ask the identical question again here? It's just wasting everyones time giving you the same comments and answers all over again.

Answer (score 4):

In bash, the string separated by spaces is split into words (word splitting). So four arguments are given to echo. If you want your blank spaces you need to add quotes to the variable `$line`, so only one argument is passed to echo.

```
cat samp.csv | while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "$line"
done
```

Output:

```
a     b           c              d
```

Comment: Thanks @Msegade  your suggestion was helpful

Comment: You got the same suggestion and more [last time you asked this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71357970/1745001).